# Низкое разрешение в Android Studio при переносе на второй экран

Tags: android-studio, разрешение

у меня проблема с запуском Android Studio на двух экранах (Оба экрана имеют разрешение 1920 х 1080). Ситуация такая: к ноутбуку подключён второй экран. Когда запускается студия, она загружается на экране ноутбука, т.к. он основной, но при переносе студии на второй экран, она превращается в мыло (Текст тяжело читать, очень низкое разрешение, при этом, на экране ноутбука всё нормально). Избежать мыла можно только сменой режима проецирования, выключив экран ноутбука, то-есть сделав второй экран основным, а затем перезапустить android stuido на нём. Вот только тогда студия запускается как надо и можно снова расширить экраны, однако, если перенести студию, запущенную на втором экране на экран ноутбука, снова можно наблюдать низкокачественную картинку.[image: Я открыл два разных проекта, как можно увидеть, на экране ноутбука разрешение ниже] В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а другие приложения?

Comment: Другие приложения ведут себя нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы было найдено. В параметрах экрана нужно выставить одинаковые значения масштаба на экранах.[image: Как видно на картинке, значения масштабов должны быть одинаковыми]